# CRM 2013 SDK LINQ Issue

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need help on the LINQ query below, the join on multiple fields seems to work, but i get

> "Invalid 'join' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid
>   property or method."

I've already tried to swap the conditions on the join to no luck

```
(from o in orderSet
join opr in OrderProductSet on o.Id equals opr.OrderId.Id
join pri in ProductPricingSet on 
new {BusinessUnitId = o.BusinessUnitId.Id, AccountId = o.Accountid.Id, ProductNameId = opr.ProductNameId.Id} equals 
new {BusinessUnitId = pri.BusinessUnitId.Id, AccountId = pri.AccountId.Id, ProductNameId = pri.ProductId.Id}
where o.name.Equals("OE-000701")
select new {
 o.name,
 o.orderId,
 opr.ProductNameId.Name,
 opr.Quantity,
 pri.Discount,
 pri.FinalPrice
})
```

Comment: Is that a typo when you say `new {BusinessUnitId = **pari**.BusinessUnitId.Id,`, or is that part of your actual code?